# How to use the "Share" function of MS Office with Gmail + Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-office, gmail, file-association, mailto

I am using MS Office 365 (more specifically, Powerpoint v. 2105) on Windows 10.

I am used to sharing files in a couple of keystrokes by going to File > Share, then sending a copy of my ppt presentation (Alt, F, Z, tab, enter for anyone interested). This works perfectly fine with Outlook.

However, I now use Gmail (in Chrome) as my primary email provider. I managed to have Gmail open all mailto links by following the steps described here (https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308783?hl=en) but Office does not take this into account and clicking on *Share* opens up Outlook instead of Chrome & Gmail.

How can I force Office to acknowledge Chrome & Gmail as the primary application for email, including to share files?

Answer (score 1):

What I found can be done is that you can use the Share function and it will launch in Outlook, but then you can drag the attachment from the unsent Outlook email message over to a composed Gmail email and drop it into the Gmail email message.  You then send the Gmail message and discard the Outlook message.  It only saves you from having to save it locally and browse for it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your needs could not be achieved.

Please refer to this article "[Email a document from Microsoft Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/email-a-document-from-microsoft-office-2754aa3a-929b-4dc6-b400-28fbf91c0d77#ID0EACAAA=Microsoft_365)", which says: If Outlook is not your default email application you'll need to configure it as the default in order to use this feature.

So I think to use Share feature to share a file as attachment, it needs Outlook app.